# Combine Android native views and QML

Tags: android, opengl-es, qml, qtquick2

In our application, we want to use QML for our main UI.

But we also have to re-use an existing Android component for A/V playback (of HLS streams with DRM) which is available as an Android View and using OpenGL.  On top of this (full-screen) View, we would like to have some QML components (eg buttons to control playback)

Hence we want to mix native Android Views and QtQuick component: I did some research and found the following approaches:

[Here](http://achipa.blogspot.be/2014/11/qml-wrappers-for-native-android.html) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mo8J-g5XPGQ) QML wrappers are created for native Android components but I don't think it allows mixing QtQuick components with the QML-Android components

[Here](https://github.com/2gis/qtandroidextensions) QML wrappers are created for eg the native EditText and they *can* be mixed with QtQuick components.  But they are rendered offline so I doubt that this approach is feasible when rendering A/V

Are there other approaches?
Suggestions/feedback/pointers appreciated!

Comment: Maybe QtApplicationDelegate.insertNativeView can be used (called from QWindow::fromWinId?). An example would be appreciated